# Apache httpd can't connect to Apache Tomcat 7

Tags: apache, tomcat, liferay, mod-jk, liferay-6.2

I'm using Liferay 6.2 EE and Apache Tomcat 7. I had to re-IP my server, and now whenever I hit my URL to my Liferay portal I receive a 404 page not found error. I restarted Apache httpd and I restarted Apache Tomcat 7. Both are up and running. My guess is that Apache httpd can't redirect my request to Tomcat. My initial configuration worked, and I haven't changed any configuration other than re-IPing the server. My `server.xml`, `worker.properties`, and `httpd.conf` files remain the same. My `mod_jk` module is loaded and the error I'm receiving in my `mod_jk.log` file is something like this:

```
 [info] Connect to 127.0.0.1:8009 failed
 [info] Failed opening socket to (127.0.0.1:8009)
 [error] connecting to backend failed. Tomcat is probably not started or is listening on the wrong port
 [info] (liferay) sending request to tomcat failed (recoverable), because of error during request sending
 [error] (liferay) connecting to tomcat failed
```

Any ideas why re-ping the server, but keeping the configuration the same would cause something like this?

Comment: can you connect to tomcat directly on port 8009;

Comment: does re-ip mean that they still are running on the same server, or did you move one of the installations onto a server with a different IP address?

Comment: I figured it out, I made a dummy and never created a new user to connect to my MySQL database under the new domain name. Thanks for your quick reponses though